# Counting sticks that touch red lines in Julia

Tags: random, julia, counting

I want to randomly "scatter" sticks of length 1 like shown in the diagram. 
I also want to count the sticks that touched the red lines.

[image]

My approach was to create normalized vectors that are oriented randomly in space. 
The problem is that they are all at the origin and I am also not sure how to identify and count those who touch the red lines

```
a = [randn(), randn()]; 
line = a/norm(a) # Normalized vector in random direction
```

Comment: Interesting question, mind sharing the full code so others can try and help?

Comment: Looks like [Count Buffon's needle experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffon's_needle_problem) unless you're adding constraints at the boundaries.  Formulas for when  a needle touches a line are given in the linked article.

Comment: Yes, it is Buffon's experiment, but I understand that the question is how to properly simulate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one of the ways to approach your question using simulation:

```
julia> using Statistics

julia> function gen_point()
           α = rand() * 2π
           range_x = 5 # anything as your lines are horizontal
           range_y::Int = 5 # must be a positive integer
           @assert range_y >= 1
           x0 = [rand() * range_x, rand() * range_y]
           xd = [cos(α), sin(α)]
           return (x0, x0 .+ xd)
       end
gen_point (generic function with 1 method)

julia> intersects(point) = floor(point[1][2]) != floor(point[2][2])
intersects (generic function with 1 method)

julia> mean((intersects(gen_point()) for _ in 1:100_000))
0.63731

julia> 2/π # our simulation recovers the theoretical result
0.6366197723675814
```

Some comments:

- In my solution I sample the angle in (0,2pi) range;
- I use `x_range` and `y_range` to define the rectangle in which the lines are scattered (`x_range` can be anything, but it is important that `y_range` is an integer);
- I have not optimized the code for speed, but for simplicity; in my `gen_point` function I generate a 2-element vector holding 2-element vectors indicating (x,y) locations of endpoints of the line; the `intersects` function - as you can see is quite simple: if y-axis of both endpoints do not have the same integer part this means that the line must intersect horizontal line of the form `y=i`, where `i` is an integer (I ignore the case where we would sample points that have exactly integer `y` axis value, as this is negligible);
- note that your plot is incorrect as x and y axes are scaled differently so actually the lines you have drawn do not all have length 1 (this is a side comment - not affecting the solution)

Comment: ah - right. I did not notice that this is `randn` not `rand` in the question. Fixed